# SPAlert and query throtelling equivalent Client Object

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How to use SPAlert  and

```
SPQuery query;
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Override;
```

in Client Object Model or the equivalent to use it in Client Object Model 2010